# How to make a bootstrap container bounce

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've started out with bootstrap and I have some problems in making a div of class "container" bounce. 
This is what I have so far

```css
@keyframes bouncing {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50px;
  }
}

#arrow {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: bouncing;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="arrow">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"> </span>
  <br />
  <a href="#">Find out more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is it not bouncing? Is it bouncing constantly? Your question is incomplete, please update your question with a working example and the problem that you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I grab @keyframes via [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) .

```css
@keyframes bouncing {
  from, 20%, 53%, 80%, to {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  }

  40%, 43% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }

  70% {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.050, 0.855, 0.060);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-4px,0);
  }
}

.bouncing {
  position: absolute;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: bouncing;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bouncing" id="arrow"> 
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"  > </span>   
      <br>
      <a href="#" >Find out more</a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6m4sezh/1)